# iPad - Getting screen size in portrait and landscape

Tags: ipad, screen

I'm using the following code to get the screen size width:

```
CGFloat width = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 100;
```

But its giving width as "668.0" in portrait as well as landscape.
How can I get different width depending on the orientation of the device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the same problem as you and all I could find is checking the orientation and calculate the height and width as follow:

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
screenHeight = orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ? 748 : 1004;
screenWidth = orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ? 1024 : 768;
```

These size are for the the iPad obvioulsy but it could work for iPhone with the right dimensions.

Personally I think it's a bit poor but I couldn't find anything else.

Comment: Instead of  
`orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`  
or  
`orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight`  
you can use `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation)` and  `UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok. In that case we can use,

```
CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
int width = viewFrame.size.width;
int height = viewFrame.size.height;
```

Comment: My class inherits from NSObject. There's no way to use view and so I'm trying with UIScreen. May be i'll to try with something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
CGSize winSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
```

winSize.width will give you width and winSize.height give you height.

Comment: I'm not using cocos2d. Is there any similar method in iPhone native SDK (not in cocos2d or something else)?